# How taxing is jQuery load + setInterval on a few large tables?

Tags: jquery, load, setinterval

I am working on a election website and have a question about jQuery and .load() and setInterval().

I have a page that has multiple candidate races with results listed at a local county level. Let's say I have 18 or so counties and 10 or so candidates running a particular race, that's a 10 column, 18 row table for that one race. There may be up to 10 races on a page.

Currently, the site is set to refresh every minute or two (client mandated) to show new results during the election. However, I'm wondering if I can just refresh the tables using .load and load in the tables dynamically and setInterval to refresh those tables (using .load) every min or so.

Is this better/worse/or same as just reloading that page? Would it be terribly taxing on the server? Due to time constraints it's either auto refresh or some jQuery solution. Any advice/thoughts is great appreciated.

An example table: [image: 1 of maybe 10 tables on a page]

Comment: The only way to know for certain is to "benchmark it". In any case, generating the table HTML on the server (or programatically/templated locally) should both be "sufficiently fast" (just make sure the data query can keep up). If using tables, the best thing to do is use the CSS "table-layout:fixed" to avoid re-calculations based on cell width. There are "neater tricks" that could be done, such as only sending/updating the values that changed with deltas/timestamps, but that becomes a much more complicated solution. *Try the simple way first.*

Comment: Also, I would *not* use `setInterval`, but rather use `setTimeout` (or the equivalent deferred) and *only* schedule a new event *after* a data-fetch completes (possibly, in error, although that might warrant increasing the duration). This will avoid "stacking" or "queuing" of requests should resources take too long to complete .. because of this finer-grained control (of data and timing) I would say that it is *better* to use AJAX than reload the page (with, say the META-equiv).

Answer (score 0):

It's really up to you.

The server processing time shouldn't make noticeable difference.

Personally, I'd just refresh the whole page. IMHO, you'll get the same result, but have 1 less thing to go wrong. You never know, even your IE 5.5 users may be able to view it.

In my opinion, the choice on technology must always be the need. If there is no driving need, choose the simpler, easier option.

Hope this helps

:)